# EF - Code first - update database after model changes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a web api application in `.net core 2.0` and I create my database using code first approach and using the commands `add-migration` , `update-database`

Now I made some changes in my model classes and created a new migration using `add-migration 2ndMigration` command. It created the migration with `Up` and `Down` methods. When I try to update database with this migration it gives me an error that

> Table 'TableName' already exists.

There's no create table command in the migration.

Why I'm seeing this error? or what's the command I need to run to update the database?

Comment: How are you attempting to update are you calling something else besides Update-Database?  Is it possible it is applying the first migration in error?  What does the migrationhistory table look like?

Comment: migration history table has only one entry for the initial migration.I'm updating the database by executing the update-database command im PM console after creating the 2nd migration. I tried it with only "update-database" command and also with the name of new migraiton "update-database 2ndMigration "

Comment: Maybe try putting a breakpoint in the Up methods and determine for sure which migration is getting called.

Comment: The tools may be hitting a call to `db.Database.EnsureCreated()`. Search your constructors and `Startup` class and move them somewhere like `Program.Main()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

run `Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges -ConfigurationTypeName YourDbConfigurationName` and add `-force` if needed.

After that use your regular `Update-database` line.